# Running AJAX code in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ajax, ios, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am developing a native application for iPhone. I would like to know if I can able to execute AJAX code in Objective C.

Thanks!
**Nilesh**

Comment: by saying AJAX, what do you think AJAX is?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260302/ajax-on-the-iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As from word AJAX the meaning is **Asynchronous JavaScript and XML**

So you need asynchronous HTTP library to fetch JSON/XML from remote server.

Take a look at these

- ASIHTTPRequest http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/
- RestKit http://restkit.org/

Comment: I am just wondering using library, can I able to send request like I did in Java script as given below:                                                                    var jsResult = $.ajax({ 
type: "POST",
url: "/classes/com/Nilesh/service.php/JSON",
dataType: "json",
data: JSON.stringify({
jsonrpc: "2.0",  
method: "test",
params: {                              
 description: $description,
 bIsPrivate: $bIsPrivate,
 isJson: true
}
 }),